# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table XYZ doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I am using JPA and c3p0 and attempting to query a table and getting back a stack trace claiming that the table doesn't exist. I can open a connection to the db in, for example, DbVisualizer, and see the table there. In fact, the debug statements from my app show it is able to make a connection and test its viability. But then it is not finding the table.

```
15:45:53.940 [http-8080-1] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
15:45:53.940 [http-8080-1] DEBUG c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4d687dcd] on CHECKOUT.
15:45:53.949 [http-8080-1] DEBUG c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnectionPool - Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4d687dcd] on CHECKOUT has SUCCEEDED.
15:45:53.950 [http-8080-1] DEBUG c.m.v.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@7930ebb [managed: 3, unused: 2, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@3e30e173)
15:45:53.950 [http-8080-1] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
15:45:53.966 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select alert0_.rrdb_key as rrdb1_0_, alert0_.date as date0_, alert0_.hostname as hostname0_, alert0_.message as message0_, alert0_.program as program0_ from reportsDb.alerts alert0_ where (alert0_.message not like '%Anomolous%') and (alert0_.message not like '%Requeue%')
Hibernate: select alert0_.rrdb_key as rrdb1_0_, alert0_.date as date0_, alert0_.hostname as hostname0_, alert0_.message as message0_, alert0_.program as program0_ from reportsDb.alerts alert0_ where (alert0_.message not like '%Anomolous%') and (alert0_.message not like '%Requeue%')
15:45:54.013 [http-8080-1] DEBUG c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4d687dcd handling a throwable.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'reportsDb.alerts' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
...
```

Here is persistence.xml (in /src/main/resources/META-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="reportsDb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>Hibernate</description>
        <class>com.pronto.mexp.common.entity.Alert</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

A subsection of applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

    <bean id="reportsDbEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="reportsDbDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="reportsDb" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="reportsDbDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <!--<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://devdbrw01:3306/mexp"/>-->
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://report101:3306/worker_events"/>
        <property name="user" value="********"/>
        <property name="password" value="********"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="4"/>
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="14400"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="1800"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- DAOs -->
    <bean id="genericReportsDbDAO" class="com.pronto.mexp.common.dal.GenericReportsDbJPADAOImpl"/>

    <bean id="alertJPADAO" class="com.pronto.mexp.dal.AlertJPADAOImpl" parent="genericReportsDbDAO"/>
</beans>
```

The thing I find suspicious is the part of the hibernate query where it tries to query `select ... from reportsDb.alerts alert0_` - how do I confirm that "reportsDb" actually stands for my data source that I spec'd in applicationContext.xml?

ETA:
The entity, Alert, looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alerts", catalog = "reportsDb")
public class Alert {

    int rrdbKey;
    String hostname = "";
    String message = "";
    String program = "";
    Date date = new Date();

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "rrdb_key", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 10, precision = 0)
    @Id
    public int getRrdbKey() {
        return rrdbKey;
    }

    public void setRrdbKey(int rrdbKey) {
        this.rrdbKey = rrdbKey;
    }

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "hostname", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 32, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "message", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 128, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "program", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 40, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public String getProgram() {
        return program;
    }

    public void setProgram(String program) {
        this.program = program;
    }

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "date", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 19, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the Entity look like? in the @Table annotation you can specify the table, catalog and schema name

Comment: @German - good point, I forgot that - edited to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your entity definition, remove the `catalog = 'reportsDb'` part, since it is being used to build the query like `select from 'reportsDb.alerts'`. 
Mysql doesn't use catalogs, AFAIK.

Comment: i discovered that i have another piece that needs to point to a different database on the same server, so i removed the database "worker_events" from my data source spec in applicationContext.xml, and added back `catalog='worker_events'` to my entity. that worked. originally, i had been trying to point catalog at the overall data source name, rather than at the database name. my test shows that catalogs do work with MySQL.

Answer (score 7):

If the table really, really, does exist in mySQL, and your using Linux/Unix, and the error shows the table name in wrong/upper-case, then the issue is that table names in MySQL are case sensitive and hibernate is upper casing them.  I'm using hibernate 4.3.

I just had this issue.  Explanation here: [lower_case_table_names=1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

--edit-- In retrospect, it's probably better to find and change any @Table or hbm.xml references to match the database.  I ran a wizard that generated an hbm.xml with uppercase names -- didn't realize that it was in my project until just now.  I'll leave this here to make people aware of the case sensitivity.

--end of edit--

Here is how I fixed it:

1. Drop the database.
2. Add this to /etc/mysql/my.conf:

   ```
   set lower_case_table_names=1 #(default value '0').
   ```
3. Restart mysqld.
4. Recreate the Database.
5. ( optional? ) change annotation/hbm.xml table references to lower case.

Comment: Steps 1-4 did not help.

Comment: I had a query with uppercase tablenames and I got always the message table doesn't exist. Thank you for your lowercase hint. Everything works smoothly now! :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was an issue of Hibernate converting my table to lower case.

My error was:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'Pluto.c_story' doesn't exist
```

Pluto is my db and C_Story is my table (NB: not c_story - lower case).

All I had to do was the following:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Well, I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

After exasperadetly eliminating every single occurence of table `XYZ` in my code, I found the actual issue: `XYZ` wasn't being referenced by JPA, but by an old, invalid mysql trigger. Maybe consider looking for the error outside of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, my mysql db was on windows but i moved it to linux which resulted in the mysql syntax of not recognizing the table.
The cause was that mysql on windows is case insensitive and case sensitive on linux
I was able to resolve this by adding :

`lower_case_table_names=1`

in my.cnf.

Also make sure to include

`[mysqld]`

at the beginning of my.cnf to avoid another error

`"MySQL my.cnf file - Found option without preceding group"`

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue. There was one SQL query that didn't pass with an error like

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'my_database_name.*' doesn't exist

But the query itself contained no *my_database_name* references or even * signs.

Comparing to other queries, we found the difference and **added ORDER BY to query and error disappeared**. Could be a hack around jdbc or c3p0 logics, but it worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was because of left outer join on subquery with alias , that is working on sql editor but not on JDBCspring, so i removed the left outer join of subquery and replaced it with left outer with no subquery

Answer (score 1):

had a similar error on my code and I changed the persistence file

```
   <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
   </properties>
```

to

```
  <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  </properties>
```

replaced  the "create-drop" with "update"

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this error. In my case, I wrote the wrong database name in jdbc datasource class.

I wrote  `cms`

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms`

```
 <bean id="jdbcDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />   
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Actually, the name of my database was `hit_kcsl`

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hit_kcsl`

```
 <bean id="jdbcDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hit_kcsl" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />   
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i mapped wrong dialect in cfg.xml, I am using MySQL57 db but used MySQL dialect. When I replaced correct dialect to MySQL57Dialect it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> Just add the property in **hibernate.cfg.xml** file then update the
>   project then run the main method and the exception will go..thank
>   you..

```
<session-factory><property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> </session-factory>
```