# Intellij is saying table from database doesn't exist, but that table isn't called in code

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

I have a MVC java application and the errror is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'bookdb.cartentry' doesn't exist,

but when I search for cartentry table in code, it doesn't exist. I don't know how intellij manages to find that table name in my code and to tell me that it doesn't exist... I have searched all code and I do not use that table name. The table used to exist, is it possible that a queue is left in the software somehow? And if so, how can I delete its track or its usage?

Here's the stack trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'bookdb.cartentry' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at com.bookStore.book.BookDao.addToCartDB(BookDao.java:81)
    at com.bookStore.book.BookDao.generateBookList(BookDao.java:36)
    at com.bookStore.book.BookController.showBooks(BookController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table XYZ doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287821/mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-table-xyz-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, no it isn't

Comment: You may wish to elaborate on why the answers in that question have not helped you. You might want to elaborate on what specifics you have done to debug your problem since as written, I think about the best any of us can do is to recommend that you look at similar questions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, well that answer claims that the table is existent in database, he can see the table there. I don't have that table in my database. I deleted it and I think it has left some tracks in my code, its queue remained in the code somehow. I tried to invalidate the cache and to find the table's occurences, but I CANNOT FIND anything.

Comment: But have you cleared any reference to it in your code's SQL queries?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yes. If i search my code for any reference, i find none. Also, I tried changing the table in name in database to cartentry, like intellij is telling me it doesn't find this table name. If i do so, at every build, intellij is adding data to the table database, although that isn't happening in the code right now. (i tried earlier, but deleted it, and somehow intelij still sees it...)

Comment: @LibrarySystem the stack trace of the exception should tell you precisely which code (classes, methods and line numbers) is throwing the exception. Read it. If you don't understand it, post it.

Comment: @JBNizet well here is the error http://collabedit.com/h44rh . I cannot get over it

Comment: The error is caused by the line 81 of BookDAO.java. This line is called by BookDao.generateBookList(), which is called by BookController.showBooks(), at line 29 of BookController.java.

Comment: @JBNizet tried to comment the lines you said caused the error, and the error looks the same. It tells me that line 81 in BookDAO is generating the error, but it is commented now. Is it possible that the cache is causing this or anything similar?

Comment: Then either you forgot to rebuild your project, or you forgot to redeploy it, or both.

Comment: @JBNizet how can I update the out folder in intellij? Rebuild of project does not update it...